# Typeahead with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

Been looking around trying to find a solution to adding images to the results using typeahead + bloodhound v0.10.2. Nothing out there really documenting how to do this in the latest version and the docs have nothing related to images. My setup is straight forward, I am calling results from JSON. In my results I have an img `src` which I want to add to the typeahead results.

**1.** Is this even possible with typeahead and will it work well?

**2.** The website has around 2000+ products, is typeahead going to handle this ok or should I look into using something else?

Here is my setup:

```
var TTproducts = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('product'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: 'json_seeds/product.json'
});

TTproducts.initialize();

$('#the-basics .tt').typeahead({
    highlight: true
}, {
    name: 'products',
    displayKey: 'product',
    source: TTproducts.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        empty: [
            '<div class="empty-message">',
            'unable to find any Best Picture winners that match the current query',
            '</div>'
        ].join('\n'),
        header: '<h4>PRODUCTS</h4><hr>',
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<img src="{{img}}" width="25px"> {{product}}')
    }
});
```

JSON:

```
[{
    "product": "Red T-shirt",
    "img": "img_seeds/products/1.jpg"
}, {
    "product": "Blue T-shirt",
    "img": "img_seeds/products/2.jpg"
}, {
    "product": "White T-shirt",
    "img": "img_seeds/products/3.jpg"
}]
```

**EDIT**

For some strange reason the above works in Safari and firefox but not in chrome. Any ideas?

Comment: @DanieleB the strangest thing... In firefox and safari it works fine, only in chrome it fails to show the image. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: open the developer tools in chrome and check if there are errors

Comment: Also, it would be more simple to help you if you use this http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I need sources to give you an accurate example on jsfiddle. It does not allow me to upload .json files, images etc and all work is in private repo.